# Is there a tool to visualize a filesystem allocation map on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

May you have ever used filesystem defragmentation tools (like Norton SpeedDisk or Piriform Defraggler) on Windows, you have probably seen such a diagram:

[image: Defraggler]

It displays a filesystem sectors map, painting (as for this particular example) sectors (sets of sectors actually, to fit the whole partition in the screen) occupied by non-fragmented (contiguous) files in blue, the opposite in red and free sectors in white (and some more colours for some more particular cases which can happen to be of interest). You can click on a "sector" and see what particular files "live" there.

Is there such a visualization tool for Linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same question, but there was no appropriate software. I tried to build davl, but did not succeed in that. So I ended up writing my own tool. You can find it here: https://github.com/i-rinat/fragview

[image: screenshot]

Use Ctrl + mouse scroll to change map scale.

Comment: Can't make it. I've tried crating an empty "build" subdirectory and running `cmake` there as you write in the README.md file but it just prints cmake help.

Comment: You should run "cmake ..", where ".." is directory with source.

Comment: Kind of better but still no luck, @rinat-ibragimov: http://pastebin.com/X5hQAmiW (Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit x86).

Comment: @Ivan, try to install these -dev packages: `apt-get install libboost-dev libsqlite3-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev`

Comment: A way better but still no luck: http://pastebin.com/nsuUYafv

Comment: @Ivan, there is no required libraries in Ubuntu 10.04. I need at least boost 1.46 for interval arithmemtics but only 1.40 can be installed. So for gtkmm-3.0, only 2.4 can be installed.

Comment: Can't you make a static build?

Comment: @Ivan, I can't figure out how to compile into one binary all gtk+3.0, and gtkmm-3.0. I'll try to create bundle with all required libraries, but it will take time.

Comment: @Ivan, https://github.com/downloads/i-rinat/fragview/fragview-bundle-x86.tar.gz   Should work on Ubuntu 10.04.4 i386

Comment: Thanks for your work, @rinat-ibragimov, but looks like libffi is missing: `error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Ubuntu 10.04 includes libffi6. I've managed to launch the application by creating bogus `libffi.so.5` as a link to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.0` but am not sure if it is going to work correctly this way.

Comment: Also, there are 2 warnings in the terminal: `(fragview:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1175:60: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/resize_grip.png'` and `(fragview:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1240:50: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/progressbar.png' files.size = 98332`.

Comment: @Ivan, as for libffi5, maybe your Ubuntu is no longer 10.04 but some later version. You can get that library from http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libffi5 (I've included it to bundle too). Also you don't have any gtk3 theme installed, hence warnings. They're not critical.

Comment: By the way, my Ubuntu has libboost 1.46 and 1.48 in repositories. I am going to try installing them and compiling from the source again... And of course I've confused it - it is not 10.04, it is 12.04 :-) I just use to wander lost in time hardly remembering what year it is... %-]

Comment: As of 2021, this builds and runs just fine.

Answer (score 9):

There's [**`dav`**](http://davtools.sourceforge.net/#screenshot), the "Disk Allocation Viewer" (supports `ext2` and `ext3`; websites dates back to 2005, could be a little bit-rotted...)

[image: visualizing the partition's fragmentation]

Comment: Thanks. This seems right the answer to the question. But it is pretty rotten indeed - it seems be intended for Fedora Core 2 environment and fails to compile as is. It is going to require some C developer work to be done to animate it...

Comment: I think a tool like this will be added to distros such as Ubuntu soon. With the advent of online defrag in ext4 and btrfs, it seems more appropriate. With other filesystems, the only way to defrag was to unmount the filesystem first.

Comment: Unmount the filesystem first is absolutely not a problem in case of desktop use. I don't even mind rebooting from a dedicated livecd to defrag. A non-esoteric defrag tool for Linux seems a miracle for me, I don't except it to appear any soon. Now all I dare to wish is to see what does my fragmentation does look like at least (I am pretty curious actually - I want to see it with my own eyes to conclude if the "ext is not fragmentation-prone" statement is truth or just an "urban legend").

Comment: Actually, offline defrag is even better (as it doesn't have to leave any files untouched because of them being locked by processes running in parallel or the file system driver itself) and so far can be preferable for desktop use (as non-stop uptime is not required).